# VueJS - Components within components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have hopefully a very easy question: I'd like to link components from within components in VueJS.

What I have so far:

**create.js** (which will be rendered with webpack to create.min.js)

```
var Vue = require('vue')
var App = require('./components/App.vue')
var Language = require('./components/Language.vue')
var vm = new Vue(App,'#app')
```

**components/App.vue**

```
<template>
  <h1>Create!</h1>
  <ss-lang></ss-lang>
  <pre>
    {{ $data | json }}
  </pre>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        name : 'Create',
        components : {
        'ss-lang' : new Language()
        }
    }
</script>
```

**components/Language.vue**

```
<template>
  <select v-model="selectedLanguage">
    <option v-for="language in languages" v-bind:value="language.value">
      {{ language.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  name : 'Language',
  data : function(){
    return {
      selectedLanguage : '',
      languages : [
        {value: 'be_en', name: 'English'},
        {value: 'be_fr', name: 'Français'},
        {value: 'be_de', name: 'Deutsch'},
        {value: 'be_nl', name: 'Nederlands'},
        {value: 'be_es', name: 'Español'}
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I open in the browser, I get the message that "Uncaught TypeError: Language is not a function". I was hoping that by connecting 'ss-lang' to the Language would be sufficient in connecting (as I added Language in the create.js).

What am I doing wrong? (eg which part of the documentation am I missing?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import the *Language* component inside *App.vue*. In your example it only was imported in the context of *create.js* :

```
//App.vue
<script>
    var Language = require('./relative-path-to-the-component/Language.vue')
    module.exports = {
        name : 'Create',
        components : {
        'ss-lang' : Language
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually tried this option before already and unfortunately this gives me the same error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Language is not a function"

Comment: Pass the Language object as is, don't instatiate it.

Comment: Ah thanks, I was still doing: new Language(). Now, no error anymore (also no select box, but that is an other story. Accepted answer ^